# How to get particular Marker id in Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on google map iOS sdk. Here I create multiple markers in separate location co-ordinates.

Now I need to add identifier such like TAG for all markers to perform action for particular marker.

If TAG or some other identifier option is not available in google map iOS sdk, please suggest me how to archive it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9):

What I do is that I simply inherit the GMSMarker and add whatever data I need to it like this, I guess this is the best and easiest option you have.

```
@interface ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker : GMSMarker

@property (nonatomic) int markerID;
@property (nonatomic) int order;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject* referenceObject;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL selected;

@end
```

EDIT:

I thought it is clear but I'll continue on how to get the data... When you create your markers and add them to the map, you create ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker and add it to the map after you fill it with everything you need, then you register any class you want as a delegate which implements GMSMapViewDelegate and you implement this method

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    // Here you are sure that your marker object is of type ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker but it won't harm to double check
   if ([marker isKindOfClass:[ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker class]]) {
       ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker* parsedMarker = (ATGoogleMapsSelectiveMarker*)marker;
       NSLog(@"%d", parsedMarker.markerId);
   }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Using custom GMSMarker class, I create marker with markerID. But how can I get particular marker using the markerID?

Ex: GMSMarker *marker = (GMSMarker *)[self.mapView viewWithMarkerID:100];

Comment: I thought it was clear on how to do it, I'll update my answer

Comment: When I subclass from GMSMarker then when assign mapView to map of marker, app will crash. because can not get Bounds of subclass.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift** solution :

My way to do it is by create an extension for the GMSMarker and using the userData property to make the GMSMarker fits my need, for me I want to add each marker with instance of Branch class (map with markers for branches of some company) and this is the way that I did:

```
extension GMSMarker {
    var branch: Branch {
        set(branch) {
            self.userData = branch
        }

        get {
           return self.userData as! Branch
       }
   }
}
```

so when I set the marker property I set it like this:

```
marker.branch = someBranch
```

Isn't that clearer and more readable than marker.userData = someBranch ??

Comment: First solution is not correct, at leaset xcode complaining and throwing NSUknownKeyException. Although, the second solution is working swiftly :)