# I want to access particular marker using useData property of marker, google maps iOS

Tags: ios

I want to all markers manipulation in google maps using array.
I want to access particular marker using useData property of marker,  google maps iOS.

Comment: Can you please specify the question a bit more clearly?

Comment: I have lot of markers on google map. I want to access a particular marker using tag (userData of marker property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **userData property** to access the the marker.

Instead **userData property** is used to store any kind of object you want to use with the marker as follows:

While creating the GMSMarker object you can set the userData property of the GMSMarker.Example:
**marker.userData = @(2);**

You can then access the userData property using:

**NSLog(@"%@",[marker.userData intValue]);**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848294/how-to-get-particular-marker-id-in-google-map-ios-sdk?rq=1

Comment: Same question but not getting solution.

Comment: To access the markers you must store the references to those marker in some array.

Comment: ok I store references to some array If we clear the map all markers references should be nil then manually we clear the array ?

Comment: How to check references are nil for particular marker.

Comment: When we clear the map, the marker references do not become nil. So the array will still have references to those markers even if we clear the map.

Comment: to check if the marker reference is nil or not you can use 

if(marker)
{
   ......
}

Comment: If we do not use array of markers references, then clear the map remove references for all markers?

Answer (score 0):

GMSMapView and GMSMarker are different objects.

To display the markers on the map, we set the **map property** of the GMSMarker as:

marker.map = mapView; (mapView is GMSMapView type object)

Clearing the map using [mapView clear] removes the markers from the map. It does not deallocate the GMSMarker objects. So marker objects still exists within their scope even if we clear the map.

Comment: Do you even know about the scope of a variable?

Comment: I know scope is local to that function.

Comment: Exactly. The existence of the marker objects also depends whether the scope is local or global.